# What connection is there between SpongeBob SquarePants and the NFL?

Tags: nfl, media

I havent played Madden for years, but I picked up last year's Madden and saw they had a Nickelodeon field with Spongebob characters.

[image]

I ask this respectfully - what does Spongebob have to do with Madden or the NFL?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a video game question, not a sports question.

Comment: I think it's okay; the poster is asking what the connection between SpongeBob and the NFL is, which is a sports entertainment question.

Answer (score 7):

Nickelodeon has, since 2021, [occasionally broadcast NFL games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFL_on_Nickelodeon). During those broadcasts, they often feature [SpongeBob SquarePants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpongeBob_SquarePants), possibly the most well-known Nickelodeon original character.

The stadium was added to Madden [to coincide with the first Nickelodeon game](https://www.theverge.com/2021/1/8/22220669/madden-spongebob-squarepants-field-reef-top-the-yard), a wildcard playoff between Chicago and New Orleans in January 2021.  Although not public, it is reasonable to guess this might have been a paid tie-in.

Comment: To add: CBS is a long-standing “broadcast partner” of the NFL. ViacomCBS owns Nickelodeon, home of SpongeBob.

Comment: Wow... I would have never guessed that Nickelodeon broadcast NFL games (I'm assuming that was in the USA).  I think most professional sports could be improved with the gratuitous addition of brightly coloured slime...